# Get the list of installed applications remotely (not WMI)

Tags: windows-server-2012

Is there a way to get the list of installed applications from Regestry without interacting with the PC directly via WMI?

I have a promoted to RW user on a Domain Controller and a bunch of PCs. I want to write an automation PS-script which will grab strings from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: You havenot tried anything. Try to give effort before putting in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WMI:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_product
```

But not recommended to use that cause it's broken. You should use the registry approach only like:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize
```